# How to view flagged comments?

Tags: support, comment, flagging

Today I wanted to see a list of the comments (rather than questions and answers) I had flagged (recently). I could not find any way of doing this. Is there an obvious way which I am missing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no way to see that, even moderators can't see a list of comments that were flagged by a specific users.

Comment: Okay. Is there any reason for this?

Comment: @user1729 For one thing: spam and offensive flags are, IIRC, supposed to be anonymous. But other than that, I don't see why.

Comment: @WillieWong What do you mean by "spam and offensive flags"? Do you mean people flagging comments for no reason and that kinda thing? Also, by "this" I was meaning being hidden from the user, not the moderators.

Comment: @user1729 "Spam and offensive flags" are flags on posts/comments that are "spam and offensive".  The flags aren't the spam. ;)

Answer (score 9):

Welcome to the club. I have been wondering for a long time.

You may be interested to keep an eye on [my question on meta.SO](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/180377/222340) on the subject. According to the only answer there, this issue is to be revisited once some server-side maintenance projects regarding flags are finished.

---

**Edit:** The update that enables comment flag history has been rolled out this week. You can admire your flags at:

`http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/users/flag-summary/userID`